# Updated kernel - still on old version

Tags: kernel, updates

So I'm trying to update my kernel. `uname -r` shows 3.4.0, and I've noticed we're up to 3.14 these days, with 3.13 seeming to be the current norm. I've ran the software updater, and it's downloaded and installed a bunch of 3.13 packages (the image, and the header, and whatever else), and then it requested a reboot. Following the reboot, my kernel version is still 3.4.0. I've also tried manually installing the three 3.14 packages, and then rebooting, but this has had no effect. What am I missing?

Comment: In the GRUB boot menu, in "Advanced Options for Ubuntu", does it list the 3.13 kernel?

Comment: What errors do you get while trying to install the packages manually ? Check the entries in `/boot/grub/grub.cnf` for the latest kernel entry. Next I would also check `/var/log/dpkg.log` for something similar to `2014-04-17 01:23:34 install linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic:amd64 <none> 3.13.0-24.46`, if your installation has gone through properly.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after digging around I realized that it's because I'm using Chrubuntu, which uses the pre-existing kernel from ChromeOS, and doesn't boot with GRUB at all. So game over as far as regular installation ideas go.

Updates can be done via script, found on Superuser: [ChrUbuntu (Acer): How to load kernel 3.8.0-16 instead 3.4.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/583269/chrubuntu-acer-how-to-load-kernel-3-8-0-16-instead-3-4-0)